# How to specify Branch with using OAuth Authentication

Tags: acumatica

Version 22 R2

How can I specify the branch that I want to operate under when logging into the API?  In the older authentication signin/signout, you could specify company and branch.  How do I do the same using the OAuth authentication?  I'm using the Resource Owner Password Credentials Flow on the Connected Application.  I'm trying to do the same as selecting the branch in the top right of the screen when using the UI.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are two answers to this question.

1. during your API call, access to the resource is determined by the default branch for the user, specified in the user maintenance screen.  So the BranchID is assigned to a created record, based on the user profile
2. user access to branches are determined by the branch-specific user roles.  Once a user role is assigned to a branch, the other branches must have at least one role assigned.  Otherwise no users can access those branches w/out a user role.

There are other rules which determine how data is shared in multi-branch environments:  [Multi-Branch support](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(3))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=29ed14e8-1cbe-4adb-8580-a0386a60ba9f)

Ideally you should specify which branch ID you wish to assign, when creating records in the system.  Acumatica handles data access by branch via user-roles.